# Smart Playlist that includes all song that are/were in another playlist

Tags: itunes, playlist, smart-playlist

I have one *active* playlist which contains about 50 songs. But I remove and add songs very commonly at this playlist. I want to have another playlist that includes all song that currently **are** and **have been** in the *active* playlist. Can someone help me to create that smart playlist?

Here is a screenshot of my first attempt but this creates a live updating clone, which is not very helpful.
[image: My first try]

Answer (score 1):

iTunes' Smart Playlist feature does not have any memory. You can only refer to songs where/how they are *in this very moment*.

You can, however, add songs to the new smart playlist that have been played in the last X hours/days.

If you can 'explain' to iTunes how to find the songs that you want to have included/excluded, you can create a smart playlist for it.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: I will try out your solution. But are there any other ways outside of iTunes to create Playlist for iTunes?

Comment: For _regular playlists_ that shall appear in iTunes you have to use a) iTunes on a PC/Mac or b) an iOS device with iTunes Match or c) an iOS device with Apple Music enabled. ## You may also use AppleScript to automate the creation of (smart) playlists.